# How do I calculate the difference of two dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have two dates in excel 01-11-2008 and 28-02-2017. I want to calculate the difference between these two dates, such that if the difference of months exceeds 6 months, then it should take as 1 Year and add the same to years. Right now I have inserted the following formula

```
=ROUNDUP((YEAR(E245)-YEAR(D245))+(IF(MONTH(E245)-MONTH(D245)>6,1,0))/12,0)
```

(E245 and D245) are cell references in Excel)

The above formula is giving an output of nine years whereas if I calculate manually I get 8 years. Can any body give a fix for this. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your method doesn't account for when the higher dates's month is less than the lower date's month. Convert each date into a number of months, subtract, divide by twelve, then round 'off' for the result.

```
=ROUND(((YEAR(E245)*12+MONTH(E245))-(YEAR(D245)*12+MONTH(D245)))/12,0)
```

Not sure which if more expensive, `ROUND` or `INT`, so you could also do

```
=INT(((YEAR(E245)*12+MONTH(E245))-(YEAR(D245)*12+MONTH(D245)))/12+0.5)
```

Adding 0.5 to the quotient will round up, and `INT` will truncate to integer. Same effect as `ROUND` with a different function.